# Does std::mutex favor the thread that owns it?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was trying to understand how [spinlock mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) works, 
so I wrote a simple code (shown below) which measures interleaving of instructions from 
different threads under protection of spinlock (or std::) mutex.

Surprisingly, it shows (in gcc at least) that  std::mutex (in contrast to spinlock mutex) 
seems to favor the thread that owns it, leading to very small instruction interleaving (at best 5%), 
unless the instruction in question is very fast (like incrementing a counter). 
In that case we can get even 50%. Spinlock mutex gives at least 80% (and typically more than 90%).

Is this a well known fact? Or maybe my code below has a bug?

I mean, I know the rule of thumb saying that mutex should be always locked for smallest amount of time. 
But I was convinced that this is so, because we want to reduce serialization of threads, 
and not because std::mutex favors the owning thread...

Here is the code:

```
#include<atomic>
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>
#include<mutex>


class SpinLockMutex{
    std::atomic_flag m_flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
public:
    void lock()   { while( m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire) )  /*do nothing*/ ; }
    void unlock() { m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release) ; }
};//class SpinLockMutex


// ******************************************
// // // std::mutex vs SpinLockMutex 
//SpinLockMutex globalMutex;
std::mutex globalMutex;
// ******************************************


// This class helps to start threads at the same time : 
class Starter{
    mutable std::mutex m_m;
    bool m_ready = false;
public:
    bool isReady() const {  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_m); 
                return m_ready; 
                 }  

    void start() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3)); 
                       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_m); 
               m_ready = true; 
             }  
};//class Starter


constexpr std::size_t   LOOP_SIZE                = 100;
std::size_t             previous_thread_repeated = 0;
Starter                 starter;


void mainFcnForThread ()
{   
    static std::thread::id  previous_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();

    while(!starter.isReady()) 
        ; //do nothing

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i!=LOOP_SIZE ; ++i){
        globalMutex.lock();
        if(previous_thread_id == std::this_thread::get_id() ) {
            ++previous_thread_repeated;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(100));
        }
        previous_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id();            
        globalMutex.unlock();
    }
}//void mainFcnForThread


int main()
{

    std::thread t1(mainFcnForThread);
    std::thread t2(mainFcnForThread);

    starter.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();  

    std::cout << double(previous_thread_repeated)/(2*LOOP_SIZE) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `sleep_for(t)` will sleep for at least `t`, but there is no upper limit.

Comment: It is possible that the OS has deprioritized these threads that are both spinning for around 3 seconds waiting on `starter`.  A more fair test might be to use proper signalling such as condition variables for both threads to signal ready, and then the starter can immediately release them.  Either way, a test involving 100 iterations spanning 10 microseconds hardly sounds sufficient.  Do you get the same results if you run the test for say, a minute?

Comment: Often times it will be preferred as it is still running unlike the other threads that are waiting/sleeping.

Comment: Whether locks are fair or not depends to some degree on the Operating System and for both Linux and Windows has changed over time.

Comment: FYI: Your `for` loop keeps the mutex locked almost 100% of the time. That may be a useful trick if your goal is to demonstrate the properties of mutexes, but it is virtually always a Bad Idea in any real program.  The best multi-threaded programs are designed not to need mutexes very often and, to not keep any mutex locked for more than a tiny fraction of the program's total run time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mutex makes zero guarantees about fairness.

Unlocking a mutex does not suspend your current thread.  Attempting to lock a mutex does not say "wait, someone else has been waiting longer, they should get a go at it".

Blocking on a mutex can sometimes put your thread to sleep.

After you unlock a mutex, you aren't "the owning thread".  You are probably a running thread.  And mutex can (and apparently does) favor running threads over threads that are suspended.

Implementing "fairness" can be done on top of C++ synchronization primitives, but it isn't free, and C++ aims not to make you pay for anything you don't ask for.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot. Your sentence "wait, someone else has been waiting longer..." made me wonder about something completely unrelated. Does std::shared_mutex give priority to writer threads, 
so that they don't wait for (presumably large number of) readers to finish? For instance, QReadWriteLock 
which is a Qt counterpart of std::shared_mutex does exectly that.

Comment: @Adrian I don't know, but that sounds like a reasonable question to ask on SO.

Comment: You might also point out that, on a multi-CPU host, a thread awaiting the OP's `SpinLockMutex` has a high probablility of also being a running thread, and it it has a high probability of winning the race against any other thread that wants the mutex, but which hasn't already entered the `lock()` method. That's probably the reason why the `SpinLockMutex` performs so much differently from `std::mutex`: A thread awaiting `std::mutex()` for any significant length of time will have been moved out of the run queue.

Comment: @Solomon Slow That also makes sense:) Thanks for both comments.