Why is push thread running until the queue reaches its max size? Why is it not like - push, pop, push, pop?
I'm trying to learn threading in C++ and not able to understand why both threads are not running one after the other? After push, the mutex is unlocked and notified through condition variable.
Why is pop thread not executing at the point? It can access the queue as the mutex is unlocked and pop the inserted value. But instead what I'm seeing is that push thread runs till the queue is full and after that pop thread runs till the queue is empty.
 #include <iostream>
    #include <thread>
    #include <future>
    #include <queue>
 
using namespace std;
 
template<typename E>
class BlockingQueue
{
 
private:
    size_t mMaxSize;
    queue<E> mQueue;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable mConditionVar;
 
public:
    BlockingQueue(size_t size): mMaxSize{size}
    {
                
    }
 
    void push(E element)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> pushLock(mtx);
 
        mConditionVar.wait(pushLock, [this](){ return mQueue.size() < mMaxSize; });
 
        cout << "Pushing " << element << endl;
        mQueue.push(element);
 
        pushLock.unlock();
        mConditionVar.notify_one();
        
    }
 
    void pop()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> popLock(mtx);
 
        mConditionVar.wait(popLock, [this](){ return mQueue.size() > 0; });
 
        cout << "Popping " << mQueue.front() << endl;
        mQueue.pop();
 
        popLock.unlock();
        mConditionVar.notify_one();
    }
 
    E front()
    {
        return mQueue.front();
    }
 
    size_t size()
    {
        return mQueue.size();
 
    }
 
};
 
int main()
{
    BlockingQueue<int> bq(5);
 
    thread t1([&](){
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            bq.push(i);
    });
 
    thread t2([&](){
        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++)
            bq.pop();
    });
 
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
 
    return 0;
}


You should use : notify_all() in this case.

@PepijnKramer There is only one waiting thread when notify_one() is called, so that will not make any difference afaik.

@TedLyngmo It does, https://onlinegdb.com/_M0l4H1Mz.  This gives both threads the chance to re-evaluate their conditions.

@PepijnKramer The output you got there could just have been the same as the one OP got. If I run your version in godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/55hsbPEd8 - "This gives both threads the chance to re-evaluate their conditions." - the waiting thread will wake up and check the condition and the already running thread will try to grab the lock. It is not waiting and will not be affected by the notification.

@PepijnKramer the only difference between notify_one and notify_all is how many waiting threads will be unblocked. Since there is only one potential thread like that here, I don't see how it can make a difference.

@wohlstad I know that, and I did see more than one thread running (t1 pushing, and t2 popping) and potentially waiting on the same condition variable... so I was a bit to quick.  But now I see the conditions ensure that either thread is making progress so that is fine

When mConditionVar.notify_one(); is called, it wakes up the other thread. Both threads are now running and will compete to take the lock. Sometimes the thread that is woken up gets it and sometimes the thread that had it last time will get it again.
If you want them to run one time each, you need to change the condition. You could add a member variable, int m_turn = 0;, and use it like this:
void push(E element) {
    unique_lock<mutex> pushLock(mtx);

    // check if it's my turn:
    mConditionVar.wait(pushLock, [this]() { return m_turn == 0; });

    cout << "Pushing " << element << endl;
    mQueue.push(element);
    m_turn = 1;            // it's the other thread's turn

    mConditionVar.notify_one();
}

void pop() {
    unique_lock<mutex> popLock(mtx);

    // check if it's my turn:
    mConditionVar.wait(popLock, [this]() { return m_turn == 1; });

    cout << "Popping " << mQueue.front() << endl;
    mQueue.pop();
    m_turn = 0;            // it's the other thread's turn

    mConditionVar.notify_one();
}

demo

Thanks for the idea to change the condition. But my case seems to be an always case where the thread which previously had lock is always getting it again. It was not a "sometimes" issue so I thought I might be doing something wrong here. I think if I make the thread sleep for sometime then it will be more visible.

@RudranshSrivastava Sure, a sleep will make it less likely that it will get the lock again, but it's still not guaranteed. Sleeping should generally be avoided for synchronization. And yes, the already running thread may have a benefit of already be running and get the lock nearly always.

@RudranshSrivastava std::mutex makes no fairness guarantees, it's very much whoever locks first wins, waking up from a condition wait probably takes longer than simply continuing round the while loop so the currently running thread tends to win https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694091/does-stdmutex-favor-the-thread-that-owns-it
